# Is it possible to generate bulk data using AWS Glue and Python from scratch?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I have a doubt regarding AWS Glue and Python, Is it possible to generate bulk data using AWS Glue and Python from scratch.
Referred the below link but I wasn't entirely sure if AWS Glue could generate data from scratch or if the documentation was explaining that the test data could be generated from raw data.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/patterns/generate-test-data-using-an-aws-glue-job-and-python.html

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code generates random text files, you can see the code listed in the Epic:

```
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
import sys
import boto3
from random import randrange
 
# Two arguments 
args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ['START_RANGE', 'END_RANGE'])
 
START_RANGE = int(args['START_RANGE'])
END_RANGE = int(args['END_RANGE'])
 
BUCKET_NAME = '{BUCKET_NAME}'
PREFIX = 'small-files/input/'
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
for x in range(START_RANGE, END_RANGE):
    # generate file name
    file_name = f"input_{x}.txt"
    # generate text
    text_str = str(randrange(100000))+","+str(randrange(100000))+", " + str(randrange(10000000)) + "," + str(randrange(10000))
    # write in s3
s3.Object(BUCKET_NAME, PREFIX + file_name).put(Body=text_str)
```

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to accept/upvote the answer.

Comment: Does aws glue cost for the job runs or the resources used while generating data?

Comment: Yes it does, Glue charges apply.

Comment: "The cost is only for the resources that your jobs use while running."
This is how it is mentioned in the above link, so does the final cost will be determined by both the job runs and the resources used?

Comment: You pay for the resources and the duration they are running. You can get full price breakdowns here: https://aws.amazon.com/glue/pricing/